# determining time points for 75% survival or 25% survival from Kaplan-Meier curve using R

Tags: r, kaplan-meier

I'm interested in determining the time points for e.g. 75% survival or 25% survival from a Kaplan-Meier curve using R.

Take for example the following K-M curve:

```
library('survival')
the.data <- data.frame(months=c(1,1.5,2,2,5, 3.5,3.75, 4,5,6), status=c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0))
answer <- survfit(Surv(the.data$months, the.data$status==1) ~1, data=the.data)
```

[image]

I know `answer` will give the median survival of 5 months, but how do you determine e.g. how many months corresponds to a 75% survival?  (I know you can go through the table generated by `summary(answer)`; I'm interested in code that will generate the result automatically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obtain the quantiles of the survival curve by specifying them manually.

In the above example, the quantiles for the `answer` survival curve can be generated as follows:

```
> quantile(answer, probs = c(0.25, 0.75))
$quantile
25 75 
 2  5 

$lower
 25  75 
1.5 5.0 

$upper
25 75 
NA NA
```

As we can see for the above, the 25th percentile gives a value of 2, while the 75th percentile gives a value of 5.

This means that **75%** survive for 2 months (1 - 0.25 = 0.75), and **25%** survive for 5 months (1 - 0.75 = 0.25).

As mentioned, this can be customised. For instance, if we want to know how many months correspond to a **60%** survival, probs is set to 0.4 (1 - 0.6 = 0.4).

```
> quantile(answer, probs = c(0.4))
$quantile
  40 
3.75 

$lower
40 
 2 

$upper
40 
NA
```

Please also refer to this [resource](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/quantile.survfit.html) for more information.